# Inheriting instance variables in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, instance-variables, self

In Objective-c 2.0 why do subclasses need to reference instance variables in parent classes using the `self` keyword?

Consider this example:

```
// a.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) Object *myObject;
@end

// a.m
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myObject;
@end


// b.h
@interface AnotherClass : MyClass
@end

// b.m
@implementation AnotherClass
- (void) someMethod {
    // error
    // Object *obj = myObject;

    // works
    // Object *obj = self.myObject;
}
@end
```

Comment: This is explained by [Kevin Ballard's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511046/) to [What is the visibility of synthesized ivars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510464/) from a few hours ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't actually defined a variable, you only defined a *property* (which implicitly defines a variable that is private). And since property are just method, you need the dot syntax. Note that `self.property` is the same as `[self property]`.

To fix this, specify a variable. I'll give you an example where the variable has a different name than the property. Most people chose the same name for both but I like to have them differ so I immediately see which one is meant.

```
// a.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    // Instance variables are "protected" by default, except if you
    // use @private or @public.
    Object *myObjectVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Object *myObject;
@end

// a.m
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myObject = myObjectVar;
@end


// b.h
@interface AnotherClass : MyClass
@end

// b.m
@implementation AnotherClass
- (void) someMethod {
    // works
    Object *obj = myObjectVar;

    // works
    obj = self.myObject;

    // the same as self.myObject
    obj = [self myObject];
}
@end
```

Note the difference when you *assign*: if you assign to your variable the object is not retained automatically. But it is retained if you use the property:

```
myObjectVar = someObject; // not retained, old object not released!
self.myObject = someObject; // old object released, new object retained
[self setMyObject:someObject]; // same as the line above
```

**Edit:** Mentioned that the synthesized instance variables are private by default, as noted by @Jason Coco. And @NSGod is right that normal instance variables are *protected* by default rather than public, fixed that.

Comment: `@synthesized` properties actually do create an ivar of their name, but they synthesize an `@private` ivar. You answer works because you've specifically created the ivar and assigned the synthesizer to it with a less restrictive access level, not because synthesizers don't generate ivars.

Comment: I haven't said that synthesizers don't generate ivars, did I? See my very first sentence. But thanks for clarifying that they are private.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I misread it in my haste skipping the parenthetical, sorry!

Answer (score 8):

They don't, provided you actually declare an instance variable in the superclass, rather than rely on the new runtime's ability to synthesize the instance variable (in addition to synthesizing the accessor methods). See [The Objective-C Programming Language: Runtime Difference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW3) for more info on instance variable synthesis.

For example, to be able to refer to the instance variable directly, you'd need to change the following:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) Object *myObject;
@end
```

to:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
// there is an implied @protected directive here
    Object *myObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Object *myObject;

@end
```

By default, instance variables are `@protected`, meaning the class and any subclasses can access the instance variables directly. `@protected` ivars differ from `@public` ivars in that you can't access them using `->`. `@private` ivars can only be accessed by the class that declares them. See [The Objective-C Programming Language: The Scope of Instance Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF127) for more info.