# How come synthesizing with an underscore is not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to synthesize variables in my iPhone app with

```
@synthesize samples=_samples;
```

with `samples` declared as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *samples;
```

However, I get a build error claiming that _samples does not exist. Why?

Comment: what does your _samples look like?

Comment: What version of xcode/are you using ARC?

Comment: I am using XCode 4.3 with ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to access the `_samples` from outside the implementation file? ivars generated through `@synthesize` are not viewable by anything outside of the implementation where the `@synthesize` was called. So if you do something like this...

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
myView._sample;
```

...you will see an error. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511046/251012
.

.

.

.

**EDIT: All of the below is wrong. Left, so that the comments make sense**

Are you declaring your ivar's and are the names spelled correctly?

When you say something like...

```
@synthesize foo = _foobar;
```

...you need to make sure that you set the instance variable in your interface like so...

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *_foobar;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *foo;
@end
```

To be clear, when you say `foo=_foobar`, `foo` is the base name to auto-generate the getter/setter's, and `_foobar` is the name of the ivar. If no ivar is declared, `@property` will auto-generate one of the same name.

Comment: Declaring the ivar is not necessary (and is no longer the recommended practice); `@synthesize` _creates_ the ivar, either with the same name as the property, or with the alternate name specified.

Comment: Jacques, can you provide a link of what is or isn't recommended practice?  It might help the OP, and myself too.  I've been using explicit ivars for years and would like to know the merits of either approach or if it's just a style preference.  Thanks!

Comment: @JasonFuerstenberg, I heard it in a WWDC session, but the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) says "Avoid explicitly declaring public instance variables. Developers should concern themselves with an object’s interface, not with the details of how it stores its data. You can avoid declaring instance variables explicitly by using declared properties and synthesizing the corresponding instance variable."

Comment: Just to be clear, the intent of my earlier comment was that this answer is _wrong_. Not explicitly declaring the ivar is very much _not_ an error.

Comment: @Jason, you need to use the `@`-symbol: `@Jacques` for me to get a notification -- I didn't see your comment until I came back to this question for another reason. Robert's link is good; [The Objective-C Programming Langugage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF122) also has a "Historical note" about ivar declarations (scroll down a bit from where this link takes you).

Comment: @JacquesCousteau you are correct. Thanks for the feedback :-) Modified my answer to try and still be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Same code is working on my side. Try to restart xcode and rebuild the project.

Comment: It could also help to try a clean build and/or delete the project's derived data (from the organizer window)

Comment: Product -> Clean .. I think thats enough for this sort of problem.