# Quick inquiry about ivars scope

Tags: objective-c, scope, instance-variables, declared-property

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the visibility of @synthesized instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510464/what-is-the-visibility-of-synthesized-instance-variables)

What would the scopes (`@private`, `@protected`, etc.) of these ivars be?

-`@property/@synthesize`

-declared in `.h`

-declared in `.m`

Comment: Class scope. As long as the corresponding objects exists, these ivars will exist too.

Comment: @ATaylor I think the OP means `@private`, `@public`, or `@protected` for the auto-generated ivars.