# Overriding property getters with lazy loading in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, overriding, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I usually lazy instantiate my @property objects in their getter methods like this:

```
@interface MyGenericClass : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIImageView *infoImageView
// ...

@implementation GenericClass

- (UIImageView *)infoImageView
{
    if (!_infoImageView) {
        _infoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderInfoImage"]];
    }
    return _infoImageView;
}
```

But when subclassing, I would often like to override some of the @properties to be more subclass specific. So I'd like to change the instantiation and do something like:

```
@interface MySpecificSubclass : MyGenericClass
//...

@implementation MySpecificSubclass

- (UIImageView *)infoImageView
{
    if (!_infoImageView) {
        _infoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SpecialInfoImage"]];
    }
    return _infoImageView;
}
```

But that's not possible, because the subclass can't access the _infoImageView iVar.

Is what I'm trying to do bad style?
Or is there a common solution / best practice for this? The only solution I see is to make the iVar public, which feels like violating encapsulation principles...

It feels like this is such a very basic question, that there must be millions of answers already out there, but after searching for hours all I could find was [Objective-C: Compiler error when overriding a superclass getter and trying to access ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113374/objective-c-compiler-error-when-overriding-a-superclass-getter-and-trying-to-ac)
, but it provides no solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to declare `_infoImageView` as a protected variable in the header file alongside with the property.
Another idea is to create a public `defaultImageView` method to call inside the lazy getter.
Something like this:

```
@interface MyGenericClass : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIImageView *infoImageView
```

...

```
@implementation GenericClass

- (UIImageView *)infoImageView
{
    if (!_infoImageView) {
        _infoImageView = [self defaultImageView];
    }
    return _infoImageView;
}

- (UIImageView *)defaultImageView
{
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlaceholderInfoImage"]];
}
```

...

```
@interface MySpecificSubclass : MyGenericClass
```

...

```
@implementation MySpecificSubclass

- (UIImageView *)defaultImageView
{
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SpecialInfoImage"]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the technique that `UIViewController` uses for its `view`:

```
- (UIView *)view{
    if(!_view){
        [self loadView];
        NSAssert(_view, @"View must be set at end of loadView");
    }
    return _view;
}

- (void)loadView{
    // subclasses must set self.view in their override of this.
    NSAssert(NO, @"To be overridden by subclass");
}
```