# Is setting a property in a custom getter a good or bad idea?

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter-setter

I have a property that I do not always need, therefore I don't want to instantiate it on view did load or an init method (I think).  I figure I could take a lazy instantiation approach and do initialization in the getter for the property...

```
-(PropertyType *)myProperty {
    if (!_myProperty)
        self.myProperty = [[PropertyType alloc] init];
    return _myProperty;
}
```

I just have a feeling that this is a bit hacky.  But it may not be. Any ideas??

-Thanks!

Comment: This will definitely help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276229/overriding-property-getters-with-lazy-loading-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks @anishparajuli, but that is a question more about using this technique with encapsulation rather than the benefits/disadvantages of using this technique in general.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very common and perfectly acceptable. You can even see this in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW13).

Relatedly, the [singleton model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7599682/4246760) is commonly used.

As always, you want to be careful to avoid [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and do this sort of thing solely as a potential performance improvement.